# Maintaining a lock on files in a stateless environment across multiple requests (Asp.Net Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-io, mutex

I am writing a Asp.Net Core application (with RazerPages) that uploads/downloads files. I have a control that uses AJAX to upload files in chunks. The files are uploaded to a subdirectory on the server. The name of the subdirectory is a guid that gets generated when the page loads.

When I remove a file from my control it sends a command to delete the associated file on the server. The issue is that for particularly large files, the delete seems to take a long time but the GUI isn't waiting for a response (so it thinks the file was already deleted). If I then try to upload the same file again I get a "Access Denied" exception because the file is still being used by another request...

I've tried to use a mutex to lock the subdirectory whenever file IO happens, but for some reason different requests don't seem to use the same mutex. If I use a static singleton mutex, it works, but this means that only one file can be uploaded/deleted at a time for the entire server.

How do I create a mutex for the subdirectory I am currently working with, and have it recognized on multiple requests?

```
public class FileIOService : IFileService
{
    public string RootDiectory { get; set; }

    public void CreateDirectory(Guid id)
    {
        // Create the working directory if it doesn't exist
        string path = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString());
        lock (id.ToString())
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AppendToFile(Guid id, string fileName, Stream content)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateDirectory(id);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString(), fileName);
            lock (id.ToString())
            {
                bool newFile = !File.Exists(fullPath);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (content)
                    {
                        content.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


    public void DeleteFile(Guid id, string fileName)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString(), fileName);
        lock (id.ToString())
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }

            string dirPath = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString());
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
            if (dir.Exists && !dir.GetFiles().Any())
            {
                Directory.Delete(dirPath, false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DeleteDirectory(Guid id)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString());
        lock (id.ToString())
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wtf are you trying to achieve with `lock (id.ToString())` ?! both are scoped to the method and the `.ToString()` will create a new string, hence a new reference every time its called. You put locks on a long lived object, i.e. instance class (usually `private object _lock = new object()`) members to prevent multiple threads accessing executing this code block at the same time.

Comment: Also, Http Requests are stateless, by nature (sessions try to add state to it). You should just redesign your application instead in a way that each upload just uses a new guid. or consider applying the saga/process manager pattern. `lock`s are just the wrong tool for this job

Comment: locks have to be reference types, but strings are a special case. .Net will only create one version of a string at a time, no matter how many places use it, they all point to the same place in memory. If I try to make parallel calls to these methods within a single request, the lock works perfectly. The issue I am having is that (for some reason) different requests seem to not use the same memory space. Even if I save the guid's ToString() to a variable before using it, the lock doesn't work across multiple requests.

Comment: You should refresh your knowledge of C#/.NET maybe. That's definitely not the case, except for interned strings (which are created at compiletime for string constants within the code

Comment: Hmmm... I was certain that this was the case. But I just created a unit test to verify that two string initialized separately referentially equaled each other and it failed, so It appears you are correct.

Comment: string interning only happens when you define the string in code, such as `string a = "Test"` and `string b = "Test"` will point to the same memory, because the compiler/runtime will put it into an internal list of strings, so only a copy exists at a time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks this is not true for strings obtained by reading a file or parsing requests etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `lock` and instead used explicitly created global mutexes. I created a private `ProtectWithMutex` method that would execute an action within a protected block of code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the specified action. Only one action with the same Guid may be executing
    /// at a time to prevent race-conditions.
    /// </summary>
    private void ProtectWithMutex(Guid id, Action action)
    {
        // unique id for global mutex - Global prefix means it is global to the machine
        string mutexId = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}" ,id);
        using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId, out bool isNew))
        {
            var hasHandle = false;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    //change the timeout here if desired.
                    int timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
                    hasHandle = mutex.WaitOne(timeout, false);
                    if (!hasHandle)
                    {
                        throw new TimeoutException("A timeout occured waiting for file to become available");
                    }
                }
                catch (AbandonedMutexException)
                {
                    hasHandle = true;
                }
                TryAndRetry(action);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hasHandle)
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
```

This prevented multiple requests from trying to manipulate the same directory at the same time, but I still had issues where other processes (Windows Explorer, Antivirus, I'm not really sure) were grabbing the file in between requests. To get around this I created a `TryAndRetry` method that would try to perform the same action over and over until successful (or until it failed too many times):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Trys to perform the specified action a number of times before giving up.
    /// </summary>
    private void TryAndRetry(Action action)
    {
        int failedAttempts = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
                break;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                if (++failedAttempts > RetryCount)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(RetryInterval);
            }
        }
    }
```

All I had to do at that point was replace all of my `lock` blocks with calls to my `Protected` method:

```
public void AppendToFile(Guid id, string fileName, Stream content)
{
    CreateDirectory(id);
    string dirPath = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString());
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileName);
    ProtectWithMutex(id, () =>
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (content)
            {
                content.CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void DeleteFile(Guid id, string fileName)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString(), fileName);
    ProtectWithMutex(id, () =>
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        string dirPath = Path.Combine(RootDiectory, id.ToString());
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
        if (dir.Exists && !dir.GetFiles().Any())
        {
            Directory.Delete(dirPath, false);
        }
    });
}
```